# empty response in ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function callQueAjax()
                            {
                            var str = $("#addNewQues").serialize();
                            $.ajax({
                                            type : "POST",
                                            data : JSON.stringify(str),
                                            url : "postNewQues",
                                            dataType: "json",
                                            contentType: "application/json",
                                            success : function(res) {
                                            //alert("yay");
                                            alert("res>>>>>"+res);

                                            },
                                            error : function(e) {
                                                alert("error" + e);

                                            }
                                            });
                            }
```

when i am sending the form data it is passing correctly to my controller, but in the response all the fields are null,plz help to get the correct data in the response.And if i remove `contentType: "application/json",` i am getting  400 Bad request as error.
Controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/postNewQues", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String submitNewQue(@ModelAttribute("EEAQBean") EEAQueBean eEAQBean) {
        // System.out.println("Obj.getReqTitle()>>>>>>"+Obj.getReqTitle());
        // Obj.getReqTitle();
        logger.info("IN Controller EEAss");
        logger.info("eEAQBean >>> "+eEAQBean.getReqId()+" >>>>> "+eEAQBean.getQueOrder());

        HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        List<EEAQueBean> addNewQueList = new ArrayList<EEAQueBean>();

        // Long addNewReqId =0L;
        String addNewQueVal = "";
        String addNewQueCode = "";

        try {

            addNewQueCode = eeaServiceImpl.insertAddNewQueData(eEAQBean);

            eEAQBean.setAddNewQueCode(addNewQueCode);
            addNewQueList.add(eEAQBean);
            data.put("addNewQueList", addNewQueList);
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            addNewQueVal = mapper.writeValueAsString(data);
            logger.info("addNewQueVal >>>>> " + addNewQueVal);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {

        }
        return addNewQueVal;
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code for your controller? It seems like that's probably the issue here.

Comment: `"in the response all the fields are null"` - What "fields"?  What is the actual response?  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: its basically a form that i am filling. all the fields while returning as response are null, like the name=null, where as i has passed name= Su

Comment: Do you get anything here->logger.info("addNewQueVal >>>>> " + addNewQueVal);?

Comment: this is what i am getting:
`addNewQueVal >>>>> {"addNewQueList":[{"requestID":null,"qOrder":null,"queOrder":0,"statusId":0,"addNewQueCode":"Q65","reqId":0,"qDesignator":null,"inScp":null,"qeustion":null,"mapId":null,"status":null,"sme":null,"assgnSmeDate":null,"assBy":null`

Comment: most of the things are null on server.are you expecting something else?

Comment: yes m expecting the data i am passing